# JavaFX FXML File takes exactly 1 second to load

Tags: java, performance, javafx, fxml

I'm building an application in JavaFX, and I'm loading FXML files for the layouts.
At the beginning, I had all of my .fxml files in my java classpath.

Since I'm kinda making a game engine, I decided to move everything outside the classpath, so I now have a file system that looks like this:

```
Folder[javafx]
    editor.fxml
program.jar
```

This is how I'm loading my FXML

```
FXMLLoader.load(new URL("file:////" + System.getProperty("jdir") + "/javafx/" + name + ".fxml"));
```

It might not look pretty, but it works (System.getProperty("jdir") is just the location of the .jar on the disc). Java finds the file, but ALWAYS takes EXACTLY one second to do so, on each file (FXML File sizes range from 1kb to 6kb)

So the problem I now have, is that my FXML takes way too long to load. Back when I had my FXML in the classpath, there was no delay.

I hope, that someone could either help me with removing this delay, or on how I can load the FXML from the .jar (From my knowlege, you can only load resources from jars via Streams, but FXMLLoader doesn't take streams, so I'm stuck.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: FXMLLoader absolutely takes streams. I package FXML as classpath resources for most projects. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.io.InputStream-

Comment: You can get resources as a `URL` via `Class.getResource(String)` and you can use streams with `FXMLLoader` via `FXMLLoader.load(InputStream)`. That aside, you need to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the delay issue because I'm not able to reproduce the problem. No matter where I put the FXML file the application finds and loads it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can move the System.getProperty("jdir") outside, because like this you will call it each time you load a fxml.

So instead of

```
FXMLLoader.load(new URL("file:////" + System.getProperty("jdir") + "/javafx/" + name + ".fxml"));
```

Do something like:

```
 String jdirProp = System.getProperty("jdir");
```

And then reuse this value on all the calls that follow.

```
FXMLLoader.load(new URL("file:////" + jdirProp + "/javafx/" + name + ".fxml"));
```

But the question is, why don't you put your fxml files under resources and just call:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("yourfile.fxml"));
```

This is the fastest and most elegant way. The delay is caused by the fact that your jar is not loaded by a classloader (since it is not on the classpath) and the resource is not readily available, so there is a bit of a delay until you can use the jar files content.

Comment: I have tried both of the suggested solutions: FXMLLoader.load(InputStream) For some reason, I just don't have that function. load() only takes URL... I'm using Java 8 and the EclipseFX plugin for Eclipse. I also can't load my files using getClass().getResource(), because I just get a NullPointerException: Location required, because I'm loading from a .jar

EDIT: Nevermind, I just had a small typo. Loading with `getResource()` works. I'm still going to need to make a performance test.

Comment: @Tewan [Here's a link to the `FXMLoader.load(InputStream)` method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.io.InputStream-). Note, it's an _instance_ method.

Comment: It's been some time but now I want to get back to this problem.
So I now load the fxml files from the classpath using `fxmlloader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/javafx/file.fxml"))`

Problem is, that I still have this delay...

Comment: You could always try a profiler like XRebel, Stackify Prefix (This is free, provides most of the functionality like Xrebel), JProfiler, etc.